# Salto de linea al imprimir una constante

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una constante en la que declaro un slider de mi app.

```
const offer = [
  {
    titleOffer: "....",
    descOffer: "...",
    image: "....",
    link: "/"
  }
]
```

En la descOffer necesito imprimir código html, ya sea para imprimir en bold o para un salto de línea. ¿Cómo debería de proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He dado con la solución.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380982/10637450

Pd. había buscado en stackoverflow en español, pero no en inglés :/